# How can I rewrite a function so it’s no longer in indeterminate form when $x$ is in the exponent?

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function, rational-functions, indeterminate-forms

I have to rewrite $f(x)$ so that it is no longer is indeterminante as the limit approaches infinity.

$$f(x) = \frac{6+2e^{-5x}}{5-16e^{-5x}}$$

I am really not sure how to go about it, though. Can someone please help me out?

Comment: I've edited the math formula, but some of your parentheses were missing, so I guessed. Also, even if you mean indeterminate, I have no idea what you mean by it here. As $x\to\infty,$ the numerator goes to $6$ and the denominator goes to $5.$ As $x\to-\infty$ it is an indeterminate form, however.

Comment: As @ThomasAndrews said, as $x \to \infty$, since the exponent is negative, it becomes $\frac{6}{5}$.  The problem is the negative side.  However, try factoring out $e^{-5x}$ from both sides \emph{first} (remember to factor it out of *both* terms!) and see where that gets  you.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews & johnnyb Thank you both for your QUICK responses. I will now attempt the question again (and I do apologize for my mistakes in the question). If you don't mind, could you please explain how As →∞, it becomes 6/5. I thought it would be ∞/∞.

Comment: $e^{-5x}\to0$ as $x\to\infty.$